# Проблемы с IPv6 при создании соединения

Tags: c++, сокет, tcp-ip, ipv6

Проблема заключается в следующем: написал общую ф-ию `initNetAddressFromEndpoint` которая по IP адресу (IPv4, IPv6, доменное имя) и порту отдает нам структуру `sockaddr_storage`. В дальнейшем эта структура передается параметром методу `connect` (кастуется перед этим к `sockaddr`). 
Передаю данной ф-ии доменное имя машины на которой dual tcp/ip стек - т.о. можем подключится к ней как по IPv4, так и по IPv6 (сервер слушает оба unspec адреса: `0.0.0.0` и `::`). Подключение по IPv4 проходит успешно, по IPv6 - *без*успешно. Может что-нибудь делаю не так?

P.S. *Что-то делаю не так - скорее стоит интерпретировать как "укажите на явные ошибки, если таковые имеются". Я понимаю, что данного кода недостаточно для того, чтобы сложилась полная картина о работе софта.*

Исходный код:

```
#if defined( _WIN32 ) && ( NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_VISTA )
typedef sockaddr_in  *psockaddr_in4, *psockaddr_out4;
typedef sockaddr_in6 *psockaddr_in6, *psockaddr_out6;
#define from_storage( SOSKADDRSTORAGE ) \
    const_cast<sockaddr_storage*>( SOSKADDRSTORAGE )
#else
typedef sockaddr_in const   *psockaddr_in4;
typedef sockaddr_in         *psockaddr_out4;
typedef sockaddr_in6 const  *psockaddr_in6;
typedef sockaddr_in6        *psockaddr_out6;
#define from_storage( SOSKADDRSTORAGE ) \
    SOSKADDRSTORAGE
#endif

void CNetUtils::initNetAddressFromEndpoint( int inFamily
    , sockaddr_storage *outAddrPtr
    , CStringUtf8 const& inAddrStr
    , unsigned inPort )
{
    memset( outAddrPtr, 0, sizeof( sockaddr_storage ) );

    struct addrinfo hints;
    memset( &hints, 0, sizeof( hints ) );

    hints.ai_flags      = AI_NUMERICSERV;
    hints.ai_family     = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype   = SOCK_STREAM;

    if( inFamily == AF_INET6 )
    {
        psockaddr_out6 addr6 = reinterpret_cast<psockaddr_out6>( outAddrPtr );
        addr6->sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        addr6->sin6_port = htons( static_cast<unsigned short>( inPort ) );

        if( inAddrStr == UNSPEC_IPV6_ADDRESS )
        {
            addr6->sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
            return;
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        psockaddr_out4 addr4 = reinterpret_cast<psockaddr_out4>( outAddrPtr );
        addr4->sin_family = AF_INET;
        addr4->sin_port = htons( static_cast<unsigned short>( inPort ) );

        if( inAddrStr == UNSPEC_IPV4_ADDRESS )
        {
#ifdef _WIN32
            addr4->sin_addr = in4addr_any;
#else
            addr4->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
#endif
            return;
        }
    }

    sockaddr_storage saddr;

    int rc = 0;
    if( inFamily == AF_INET6 )
        rc = ::inet_pton( inFamily, inAddrStr.c_str(), &reinterpret_cast<psockaddr_out6>(&saddr)->sin6_addr );
    else
        rc = ::inet_pton( inFamily, inAddrStr.c_str(), &reinterpret_cast<psockaddr_out4>(&saddr)->sin_addr );

    if( rc )
    {
        hints.ai_family = inFamily;
        hints.ai_flags |= AI_NUMERICHOST;
    }

    InetAddressFormat iaf_dummy = iafUnknown;

    SockAddresses sockAddrs;
    getAvailableSockAddresses( sockAddrs, iaf_dummy, inAddrStr, inPort );

    if( sockAddrs.empty() )
    {
        #ifdef _WIN32
                ENetStatusException e( "CSimpleSocket: getaddrinfo failed", getSocketErrorCode() );
        #else
                const char *err_str = gai_strerror( rc );
                ENetException e( err_str );
        #endif
                throw e;
    }

    SockAddresses::const_iterator saIt =
            std::find_if( sockAddrs.cbegin(), sockAddrs.cend(), [=]( SockAddrInfo const& sa ) -> bool
                { return sa.p_family == inFamily; }
            );

    // this shouldn't happen
    if( saIt == sockAddrs.cend() )
    {
        CStringBuilder buf;
        buf << "Error in CNetUtils::initNetAddressFromEndpoint: \n"
            << "attempt to init netaddress for unreachable inet family [ "
            << "inetFamilyCode=" << inFamily << " ] ";

        throw ENetException( buf.text() );
    }

    SockAddrInfo const& sa = *saIt;

    if( inFamily == AF_INET6 )
    {
        memcpy( &reinterpret_cast<psockaddr_out6>( outAddrPtr )->sin6_addr
            , &sa.p_addr
            , sa.p_addr_len );
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy( &reinterpret_cast<psockaddr_out4>( outAddrPtr )->sin_addr
            , &sa.p_addr
            , sa.p_addr_len );
    }

    if( inFamily == AF_INET6 )
    {
        psockaddr_out6 addr6 = reinterpret_cast<psockaddr_out6>( outAddrPtr );
        addr6->sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        addr6->sin6_port = htons( static_cast<unsigned short>( inPort ) );
    }
    else
    {
        psockaddr_out4 addr4 = reinterpret_cast<psockaddr_out4>( outAddrPtr );
        addr4->sin_family = AF_INET;
        addr4->sin_port = htons( static_cast<unsigned short>( inPort ) );
    }
}
```

*getAvailableSockAddresses - по IP/порту отдает нам все возможные sockaddr'ы*

```
void CNetUtils::getAvailableSockAddresses( SockAddresses& outAddresses
    , InetAddressFormat& outUnspecAddr
    , CStringUtf8 const& inAddrStr
    , unsigned inPort  )
{
    if( inAddrStr == UNSPEC_IPV4_ADDRESS )
    {
        outUnspecAddr = iafIPv4;
        return;
    }

    if( inAddrStr == UNSPEC_IPV6_ADDRESS )
    {
        outUnspecAddr = iafIPv6;
        return;
    }

    struct addrinfo hints, *resaddr = 0;
    memset( &hints, 0, sizeof( hints ) );

    hints.ai_flags      = AI_NUMERICSERV;
    hints.ai_family     = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype   = SOCK_STREAM;

    int rc = getaddrinfo( inAddrStr.c_str(), CStringUtf8::fromInt32( inPort ).c_str(), &hints, &resaddr );
    if( rc == 0 )
    {
        struct addrinfo *ai = resaddr;
        while( ai != 0 )
        {
            SockAddrInfo sa;
            sa.p_family = ai->ai_family;
            sa.p_sock_type = ai->ai_socktype;
            sa.p_addr_len = ai->ai_addrlen;
            memcpy( &sa.p_addr, ai->ai_addr, sizeof( struct sockaddr ) );

            outAddresses.push_back( sa );

            ai = ai->ai_next;
        }
    }

    if( resaddr )
        freeaddrinfo( resaddr );
}
```

Comment: Кода, возможно, много, поэтому извините, если не рассказал про _что-то_, про что следовало рассказать.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ найден: вместо структуры `sockaddr` следует использовать универсальную структуру `sockaddr_storage`, размер которой позволяет хранит всю информацию как об `IPv4`-адресе, так и об `IPv6`.

Т.о.:

```
    // typeof(sa->p_addr) = sockaddr
    memcpy( &sa.p_addr, ai->ai_addr, sizeof( struct sockaddr ) );
```

следует заменить на:

```
    // typeof(sa->p_addr) = sockaddr_storage
    memcpy( &sa.p_addr, ai->ai_addr, ai->addrlen );
```